PYTHON API-request 'str' object has no attribute 'data'
I'm trying to get data from a jobs API (https://arbeitnow.com/api/job-board-api). The requests are going completely fine, and I can access a whole dict with other 'data', 'links' and 'meta' dicts. The things is that when I try to access what is inside the data dict, I get this error: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'.
import requests
import json

url='https://arbeitnow.com/api/job-board-api'

def get_jobs():
    req=requests.get(url)
    if req:
        jobs=json.loads(req.text)
        for job in jobs:
            print(job.data) 
    else:
        print('error: ', req.status_code)
    
get_jobs()

If I try it like this:
for job in jobs:
    print(job)

It works fine to print the three dicts I said before (data, links and meta)
The problem is really how to access dict inside dict.

The object returned by requests.get() will always be a Response object thus making your if/else construct pointless. Always test the HTTP status code - e.g., raise_for_status()

The returned JSON is a dictionary of lists of dictionaries.  for job in jobs: just prints the top-level keys (data, links, meta) which contain lists of more items.  Use jobs['data'] to access the list value of the data key.
To access the data list, use:
import requests
import json

url='https://arbeitnow.com/api/job-board-api'

req = requests.get(url)
jobs = req.json()  # `requests` has a `.json()` helper function
for list_item in jobs['data']:  # iterate the list under the `data` key
    for key, value in list_item.items():  # iterate keys/values of each list item
        print(f'{key!r}: {value!r}')
    print()

Output:
'slug': 'copywriter-munich-487055'
'company_name': 'Liebl & Frank GmbH'
'title': 'Copywriter (m/w/d)'
'description': '<h2>Jobbeschreibung</h2>\n<p>Du bist ein kreatives Organisationstalent und suchst einen Job, bei dem du gemeinsam mit motivierten Kolleginnen und Kollegen zusammenarbeitest und selbstständig im Thema Werbetexten, Social-Media und Content Erstellung umsetzt, darfst. Dabei arbeitest du gerne strukturiert und mit klaren Vorgaben?</p>\n<p>Dann bewirb dich jetzt als <strong>Copywriter</strong> in Vollzeit (m/w/d).</p>\n<h2>Deine Aufgaben:</h2>\n<ul>\n<li>Erstellung von Content für Social Media: Creatives und Designs, Copys firmenintern sowie für unsere Kunden</li>\n<li>Inhaltliche Konzeption von Broschüren für Print und Direct Mailings</li>\n<li>Nachverfolgung der Wirksamkeit unserer Marketingmaßnahmen</li>\n<li>Implementierung und Verbesserung unserer Prozesse</li>\n<li>Unterstützung im Projektmanagement und bei Kundenprojekten</li>\n<li>Nach Wahl und Interesse oder Fähigkeiten: Pre-Production-Planung von Imagefilm-Kampagnen sowie Sichtung und Überarbeitung der Aufnahmen bedingt Postproduktion, ggf. auch. Videoschnitt und Bearbeitung des Materials gemäß Styleguides</li>\n</ul>\n<h2>Stellenanforderungen</h2>\n<p>Deine Qualifikation:  </p>\n<ul>\n<li>Ein Studium und/oder eine Ausbildung als Germanist, im Bereich Social-Media oder Online-Marketing sind von Vorteil, aber nicht notwendig</li>\n<li>Du interessierst dich für Marketing, Social Media &#x26; Kommunikation und kannst dich gut in neue Systeme einfinden</li>\n<li>Gute Vorkenntnisse in diesen Bereichen, insbesondere Online-Marketing, sind von Vorteil</li>\n<li>Analytisch-methodisches und strukturiertes Denken, Organisationsfähigkeit, Ergebnis- und Lösungsorientierung sowie ausgeprägte Teamfähigkeit gepaart mit sicherem Auftreten und einer selbstständigen Arbeitsweise</li>\n<li>Du hast eine schnelle Auffassungsgabe und hohe Disziplin</li>\n<li>Du besitzt die Fähigkeit, bestehende Prozesse zu befolgen</li>\n<li>Perfektes Deutsche in Wort und Schrift</li>\n</ul>\n<h2>Warum Liebl &#x26; Frank GmbH?</h2>\n<ul>\n<li><strong>Tolle Arbeitsatmosphäre:</strong> Der Umgang untereinander ist sehr kollegial und familiär. Wir ziehen alle am gleichen Strang und motivieren uns gegenseitig, Bestleistungen zu erzielen und persönlich zu wachsen.</li>\n<li><strong>Unsere Dienstleistungen:</strong> Wir verkaufen mit unseren Marketingsystemen ein modernes Produkt, hinter dem wir stehen. Wir wissen, was unsere Kunden brauchen und wir sind uns sicher, dass wir durch unsere geilen Marketingideen die Welt zu einem schöneren Ort machen und gute Mitarbeiter bekommen durch uns die besten Arbeitsplätze.</li>\n<li><strong>Sicherer Arbeitsplatz:</strong> Jede Person, die wir einstellen, soll langfristig mit uns wachsen. Das Ziel jeder Einstellung ist eine unbefristete Übernahme.</li>\n<li><strong>Stetige Weiterentwicklung:</strong> In den vergangenen Jahren haben wir uns vom kleinen Start-up zum branchenbekannten Partner entwickelt. Bei uns steigst du direkt in die Aufgaben ein, unterstützt Liebl &#x26; Frank dabei weiter zu wachsen und kannst dich dadurch jeden Tag selbst weiterentwickeln. Regelmäßiges Feedback von deinem Mentor unterstützt dich dabei und hilft dir, stets den Überblick zu behalten, wo du gerade stehst.</li>\n</ul>\n<h2>Wir bieten:</h2>\n<ul>\n<li>Kostenlose Getränke, Obst und Snacks</li>\n<li>Gemeinsame Unternehmungen wie zusammen Essen oder sportliche Aktivitäten (Wir zahlen ;)</li>\n<li>Du hast ein cooles Team. Wir geben alle Gas, ziehen an einem Strang, lieben Erfolg und gute Leistungen – hier herrscht einfach ein positiver Teamspirit</li>\n<li>Teilnahme an Veranstaltungen, Messen, Events</li>\n<li>Du erhältst eine umfangreiche Schulung und Einarbeitung und erhältst regelmäßige Weiterbildungen</li>\n<li>Du hast jederzeit Zugriff auf unsere Wissensplattform und somit die Möglichkeit, alle Abläufe und Prozesse und sonstige Informationen in Form von kurzen Videos anzusehen, um deinen Arbeitsalltag noch effizienter gestalten zu können</li>\n<li>Du hast die Chance, mit uns zu wachsen, dich weiterzuentwickeln,</li>\n<li>Arbeiten im Büro in München in einer geilen, modernen Arbeitsumgebung mit MacBooks &#x26; Co.</li>\n<li>Zugang zu unserem Firmen Fitness- und Wellnessprogramm</li>\n</ul>\n<p>Klingt ganz nach dir? Dann bewirb dich jetzt! Wir freuen uns darauf, dich kennenzulernen.</p>\n<p>Find more <a href="https://www.arbeitnow.com/english-speaking-jobs">English Speaking Jobs in Germany</a> on Arbeitnow</a>'
'remote': False
'url': 'https://www.arbeitnow.com/jobs/companies/liebl-frank-gmbh/copywriter-munich-487055'
'tags': ['Marketing and Communication']
'job_types': ['Contract', 'berufseinstieg']
'location': 'Munich'
'created_at': 1731786544

'slug': 'intern-working-student-operations-berlin-189463'
'company_name': 'Sempi'
'title': 'Intern/Working Student Operations'
'description': '<p>Sempi is an AI-powered reselling assistant that makes it extremely easy for users to sell their second-hand items across multiple platforms. Our mission is to optimize sales success and provide a seamless experience for sellers in the growing circular economy.</p>\n<p>As an early-stage startup, you’ll have the opportunity to make a meaningful impact, working directly with the founding team to shape the future of Sempi. We value innovation, ambition, attention to detail, and customer orientation as we expand and improve our product.</p>\n<p>We secured initial funding from Antler and are backed by Climate X, the climate accelerator from the Berlin Innovation Agency.</p>\n<p>Do you want to contribute to a project with real-world impact? Are you passionate about creating sustainable solutions in the circular economy? Then we would love to have you on board as our Operations Intern!</p>\n<h2>Tasks</h2>\n<ul>\n<li>Optimize our product listings and inventory management across multiple platforms to maximize sales potential.</li>\n<li>Analyse sales performance and provide data-driven recommendations to improve operational efficiency and customer satisfaction.</li>\n<li>Assist in the implementation of internal processes to streamline daily operations, from product onboarding to after-sales support.</li>\n<li>Troubleshoot customer issues, working closely with sellers to ensure a smooth and successful transaction experience.</li>\n<li>Collaborate with the co-founders on strategic initiatives to improve platform features and user engagement.</li>\n<li>Create and maintain clear documentation for operational processes, identifying areas for automation and improvement.</li>\n</ul>\n<h2>Requirements</h2>\n<ul>\n<li>You are in your final semester at a top-tier university.</li>\n<li>Based in Berlin or willing to relocate to Berlin.</li>\n<li>You are looking for an internship starting soon and are available for at least three to six months.</li>\n<li>Strong interest in the circular economy, sustainability, and marketplaces.</li>\n<li>You already acquired previous experience in operations, customer service, and project management.</li>\n<li>Excellent organizational skills with strong attention to detail.</li>\n<li>Ability to think analytically, with an understanding of how to interpret sales and operational data to drive decision-making.</li>\n<li>Proactive, process-driven, and excited about working in a fast-paced, dynamic environment.</li>\n<li>Fluent in English and German.</li>\n<li>Strong communication skills, especially when dealing with customer queries and resolving issues.</li>\n</ul>\n<h2>Benefits</h2>\n<ul>\n<li>A hands-on experience working with the 3 co-founders in an early-stage startup, giving you a unique opportunity to shape the future of Sempi.</li>\n<li>Flexibility with a hybrid working mode and flexible working hours, centrally located and well-connected office space.</li>\n<li>The chance to work on an impactful project in the fast-growing circular economy sector.</li>\n<li>Extensive onboarding and regular check-ins with the founding team to ensure your personal and professional development.</li>\n<li>An innovative and supportive working environment where new ideas and approaches are encouraged.</li>\n<li>An attractive financial compensation.</li>\n</ul>\n<p>If you are excited about our mission and believe you can contribute, we want to hear from you!</p>\n<p>Find <a href="https://www.arbeitnow.com/">Jobs in Germany</a> on Arbeitnow</a>'
'remote': False
'url': 'https://www.arbeitnow.com/jobs/companies/sempi/intern-working-student-operations-berlin-189463'
'tags': ['Business Operations']
'job_types': ['Working student', 'no experience required / student']
'location': 'Berlin'
'created_at': 1731772144

'slug': 'niederlassungsleiter-dusseldorf-188914'
'company_name': 'Bernd Ulrich IT- Recruiting'
'title': 'Niederlassungsleiter Düsseldorf'
'description': '<p><strong>Unser Mandant</strong> ist ein IT-Dienstleistungsunternehmen, als Tochtergesellschaft einer bundesweit erfolgreichen Unternehmensgruppe mit mehr als 500 namhaften Kunden. Das Unternehmen expandiert nachhaltig und erfolgreich in einem dynamischen Marktumfeld. Das Leitungsportfolio umfasst Arbeitnehmerüberlassung, Freelancervermittlung und Personalvermittlung.</p>\n<h2>Aufgaben</h2>\n<ul>\n<li>Sie werden unser Wachstumsmotor. Neben dem operativen Personaldienstleistungsgeschäft sind Sie für den Auf- und Ausbau unseres neuen Standortes in Düsseldorf verantwortlich</li>\n<li>Sie betreuen und beraten die Kunden zu unserem Leistungsportfolio oder projektbezogenen Fragestellungen</li>\n<li>Sie übernehmen die Vertrags- und Preisverhandlungen mit Ihren Kunden führen sie zum erfolgreichen Abschluss</li>\n<li>Sie verkaufen unsere Dienstleistung gemeinsam mit Ihrem Team in folgenden Fokusbranchen: Public, Energy, Industry, Banking, Insurance und Consulting</li>\n</ul>\n<h2>Qualifikation</h2>\n<ul>\n<li>Sie verfügen über ein abgeschlossenes Studium oder eine vergleichbare Qualifikation</li>\n<li>Durch Ihre Vertriebserfahrung in der Personaldienstleistungsbranche begeistern Sie Ihre Kunden und platzieren erfolgreich IT-Experten</li>\n<li>Sie setzen Ihr ausgereiftes IT-Knowhow ein, um sich mit den Kandidaten und Kunden auf Augenhöhe auszutauschen</li>\n<li>Verhandlungssichere Sprachkenntnisse in Deutsch und Englisch zur Kommunikation mit unseren Ansprechpartnern und Experten sowie gute MS-Office Kenntnisse runden Ihr Profil ab</li>\n</ul>\n<h2>Benefits</h2>\n<ul>\n<li>Anerkennung, Wertschätzung und Respekt für Ihre Leistung! Ihre Arbeit wird bei uns belohnt. Mit unserem offenen Provisionsmodell können Sie sicher sein, dass Sie für Ihren Erfolg, richtig entlohnt werden</li>\n<li>Es werden flexible Arbeitszeitmodelle, die Möglichkeit zu Remotearbeit sowie eine Teilnahme an unseren Workations angeboten, die Ihnen die Vereinbarkeit von Karriere und Privatleben ermöglichen</li>\n<li>Ein Smartphone, ein Firmenwagen, Corporate Benefits, vermögenswirksame Leistungen, die Möglichkeit ein Business Bike zu leasen, ein unbefristeter Arbeitsvertrag mit 30 Tagen Urlaub und eine betriebliche Altersvorsorge runden das Angebot ab</li>\n</ul>\n<p>Mit diesem Angebot wenden wir uns an Bewerber mit Führungserfahrung für den Aufbau der neuen Niederlassung in Düsseldorf. Es wird eine erfahrene, vertriebsnah aufgestellte Persönlichkeit, in der Funktion des Niederlassungsleiters gesucht.</p>\n<p>Find more <a href="https://www.arbeitnow.com/english-speaking-jobs">English Speaking Jobs in Germany</a> on Arbeitnow</a>'
'remote': False
'url': 'https://www.arbeitnow.com/jobs/companies/bernd-ulrich-it-recruiting/niederlassungsleiter-dusseldorf-188914'
'tags': ['Management', 'Team Leader']
'job_types': ['berufserfahren']
'location': 'Düsseldorf'
'created_at': 1731768544

... etc.

